# Bootstrap 5 - Access file input label (where filename is displayed)

Tags: javascript, file, input, filenames

I am looking for a way in javascript to access where the filename of an upload type field is displayed, with bootstrap 5 : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#file-input

Currently, the rendering is this:

```html
<div>
  <label for="formFileLg" class="form-label">Large file input example</label>
  <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="formFileLg" type="file">
</div>
```

And I don't understand how could I manually change the 'No file chosen' to something dynamic in javascript (well I already have the code to determine what I want to display, but no way to access it)

Answer (score 1):

```
In jQuery:

<div>
  <label for="formFileLg" class="form-label">Large file input example</label>
  <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="formFileLg" type="text" Placeholder="Click toupload file">

  <input style="display:none" id="uploadform" type="file">
</div>
```

```js
$('#formFileLg').click(function() {
  $('#uploadform').trigger('click');
});
```

You can stile a `DIV` to your desire, give it an ID and use it as a base element for upload click